# Update multiple tables at a time in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql-update

I have a database with few thousands tables (a separate table for each day's daily record). All these daily tables have the same structure.

My issue is, I want to apply an update operation in all these tables with the easiest way possible.

e.g.

```
UPDATE table_1 SET colA = 'somevalue' WHERE <condition>;
UPDATE table_2 SET colA = 'somevalue' WHERE <condition>;
```

so it's clear that all the parameters will remain same except for the table name

Any help on this will be highly appreciated.

Thanks,
Kushal.

Comment: You can organize execution in a loop.

Comment: Create a `pl/sql procedure` and it'll handle the rest

Comment: yeah, the option that I had in my mind was Stored Procedures. I was wondering if there was any other way. I will try with Stored Procedures once.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Read the table names from information_schema and build your update statement with it. Write this to a file and read it again.

```
SELECT CONCAT('UPDATE ', table_name, ' SET col = "whatever" where condition = true;')
INTO OUTFILE '/tmp/my_update.sql'
FROM information_schema.tables t
WHERE t.table_schema = 'your_database_name';

SOURCE '/tmp/my_update.sql';
```

and that's it.